# Why the development of mathematics was very slow between Ancient Greece and Descartes?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, math-history

Update :I asked This question on HSM [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/16120/why-the-development-of-mathematics-was-very-slow-between-ancient-greece-and-desc)

---

In my studies of mathematics (I am not very good at mathematics, I only studied real analysis and some linear algebra), I noticed that mathematics can be divided into two major parts. One part is Ancient Greek mathematics. This part has achievements in geometry and arithmetic and their connections. The other part is modern mathematics from Descartes to today. This part has discoveries in calculus, number theory, topology, and many other fields. But what happened between these two eras? In my studies, I did not find many theorems from this period or any great breakthrough at all.

It seems like mathematics stopped there and only resumed in the 1600s. But why is that? Mathematics is not like physics that needs experiments to test theories and wait for centuries such that their tools become good enough. Mathematics only relies on logic. So why did many mathematical concepts take millennia to develop? As far as I know, mathematics can be divided into fields like topology, analysis, number theory, algebra, geometry and combinatorics. etc. Most of these fields or concepts took more than a millennium to appear. The first major one was geometry, and it appeared in Ancient Greece. All the others did not exist until after the 1600s, like topology or number theory, or they were too small and narrow to be considered as separate fields before. So why is that? Even if calculus took 1000 years to be discovered I heard that many math fields don't rely on analysis like abstract algebra, graph theory etc.

I heard that philosophy held back mathematics for millennia, like Archimedes could have discovered calculus if he did not think too much about philosophy and infinity . So why was the development of mathematics slowed for a millennium? or in other words why the development of mathematics was very slow between Ancient Greece and Descartes.

I think this question might  have too long answers because as a user mention before in one of my old questions  "the history of mathematics will be very hard to be broken down into a couple of paragraphs" and so I will ask for books or reference that answer this question if the answer is too long  .

Comment: This question would be better-suited to [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com). It also may need restricting to appropriate cultures. The [medieval fate of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Medieval_mathematics) was not the same in Europe as in India or the Islamic world, for example, although even European developments occurred. Lastly, a more explicit focus on the origination of topics (areas, fields? I'm not sure what to call them) rather than theorems would probably improve the question too. As to the answer, topics await motivating problems.

Comment: @J.G. Should I ask on HSM now or wait  if someone will answer this question?

Comment: Ideally a moderator would migrate it, but I suggest making improvements while you wait to see if they do it. At least then if you do manually repost the resulting question will be better.

Comment: A lot of stuff, not just mathematics, stagnated in Europe between ancient Greece and Descartes. But much progress was made in the Islamic world, in India, in China.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know than many fields have this problem but mathematics is different "Mathematics is not like physics that needs experiments to test theories and wait for centuries such that their tools become good enough. Mathematics only relies on logic." even the development of math in Islamic world, in India, in China cannot be compared to ancient Greek era

Comment: and pure math don't need the type of motivation that required some experiment or spending a lot of money  for some tools so Why pure math development was so slow 
? does that    philosophy held back mathematics ?

Comment: It's true a lack of experiments held back empirical sciences, but the reason for the lack of experiments was people not thinking they were worth doing. Perhaps people in certain times and places didn't think it was worth doing the things that would lead to certain kinds of new developments in mathematics. And the strange truth is a lot of "pure" mathematics was developed because of specific real-world motivations.

Comment: Do you actually know anything of the history of mathematics outside of Europe prior to about 1400 CE?

Comment: @DavidK Not very much but I am saying that in my study of math from elementary school to college math 99% of the theorems that I studied was from ancient Greek ( and every thing before that) era and the modern era. even the theorems that I haven't studied yet and just heard of it there is not much of them in this era and I didn't know if  this era has a great breakthrough and even if there were some of them, I think therewere not very relevant now since in the modern era there is not much of these theorem is taught in schools.

Comment: That could speak to what's deemed pedagogically relevant now. After the Middle Ages, a lot of mathematics was reinvented with rigour, or reinvented in Europe, resulting in an overly recent attribution.

Comment: It wasn't just physics, pie. How many European philosophers can you name, after Plato but before Descartes? How many playwrights, after Euripides but before Shakespeare? How many sculptors after Ancient Greece but before Renaissance Italy?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well 0. But even outside of Europe  in China or India or Abbasid Caliphate the development of math  was not much as ancient Greece